# fulltextsqlquery exclude records with blank department

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery

The following FullTextSQLQuery returns results:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, WorkEmail, HireDate 
FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' 
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
```

The following FullTextSQLQuery does not return any results:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, WorkEmail, HireDate 
FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' 
AND Department != '' 
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
```

The only difference is the addition of "Department != ''" in the second query. I know there are records in which Department is blank. Why am I not getting any results for the second query?

**UPDATE**

When I query for text within the Department column, I don't get any results, even though there is text in the column:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, WorkEmail, HireDate 
FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' 
AND Department LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
//no results!
```

If I do the same query on a different column, I get results:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, WorkEmail, HireDate 
FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' 
AND PreferredName LIKE 'A%'
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
//results!
```

Also if I do a People Search through the UI for Department:"name of department" (using an actual department name), I get results, so I know for sure that Department is being crawled. Does anyone have some insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, WorkEmail, HireDate
FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' 
AND Department LIKE '_%'
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
```

## Edit:

This actually looks like a problem with the Department field itself.

For one, "FullTextSQLQuery does not track whether a crawled property is null. Null values are not stored. Therefore if you OR two managed properties together and there is not a value for both, then the record will not be returned." [FullTextSQLQuery tips](http://treenovum-wss.com/alavpa/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=85)

Also, I found a scraped forum post (that I can't link to, since it was scraped) that said that including the Department field (as well as OfficeNumber or JobTitle) always returned 0 results. This **may** be an issue with the property not being crawled.

You could try using [MOSS Search Coder](http://mosssearchcoder.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex.

Good luck.

Comment: No results for that, either.

Comment: `*` is the wildcard character in SharePoint Search SQL (which is used with FullTextSqlQuery). I tried `AND Department LIKE '*'`, which retured no results.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking of the CONTAINS syntax, which uses *. But, using LIKE with _% or % yields zero results. I've also tried `CONTAINS(Department, '*')` which gives me an error: "Your query included only common words and / or characters, which were removed. No results are available. Try to add query terms."